# When should NullabilityInfo.ReadState vs. NullabilityInfo.WriteState be used when determining reference type nullability in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable-reference-types

Following the introduction of nullable reference types in C#, `NullabilityInfoContext` and `NullabilityInfo` were introduced into the `System.Reflection` library to allow us to see the nullability of properties, parameters, etc.

Much of the documentation and community answers give examples like this:

```
NullabilityInfoContext context = new();
var nullabilityInfo = context.Create(myPropertyInfo);

Console.WriteLine(nullabilityInfo.ReadState);    // Nullable
Console.WriteLine(nullabilityInfo.WriteState);   // Nullable
```

But this doesn't actually explain, in a real-world scenario, when one should determine nullability based on the `ReadState` property, or the `WriteState` property. Why are they even distinct? Are there any situations where `WriteState` would be Nullable and `ReadState` would be NonNullable or vice-versa?

Perhaps there is something I'm missing, but as far as I can tell, when you specify a nullable reference type with `?`, it is nullable in the context of both reading and writing?

Answer (score 3):

> as far as I can tell, when you specify a nullable reference type with
> ?, it is nullable in the context of both reading and writing

Nope, here's one example.  So I would not rely on one or the other.  I also believe that there's a way to change whether this is evaluated for public only or not, but I'm not a fan of this feature so I don't use it (not the design, the implementation).

```
class Example
{
    public string? Read { get; }
    public string? Write { set => value = null; }
}

static void Main()
{
    NullabilityInfoContext context = new();
    var write = typeof(Example).GetProperty("Write");
    var read = typeof(Example).GetProperty("Read");
    var writeInfo = context.Create(write);
    var readInfo = context.Create(read);
    Console.WriteLine(writeInfo.ReadState);
    Console.WriteLine(writeInfo.WriteState);
    Console.WriteLine(readInfo.ReadState);
    Console.WriteLine(readInfo.WriteState);
}
```

Output:

> Unknown
>
> Nullable
>
> Nullable
>
> Unknown

Answer (score 0):

This is the original issue/proposal on GitHub repo.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29723

It's worth looking at the conversation, I hope they can give you a better idea on that.